# Выделение текущей страницы в меню, желательно на PHP

Tags: php

Есть стандартная менюшка (состоящая из ul и li) в шапке сайта:

```
Главная | Карта | FAQ | Авторизация | Блог
```

Суть вопроса:

Как сделать, чтобы если пользователь находился на Главной, то кнопка Главная, например, становилась красным цветом? (например в li менялся пункт color)

Comment: покажите код, которым вы формируете html *менюшки*. И как вы определяете, на какой странице вы находитесь?

Comment: <ul class="menu">
       <li><a href="http://sampwar.ru/news">Главная</a></li>
        <li><a href="http://sampwar.ru/news">Каталог</a></li>
   </ul>      Меню самое обычное

Comment: Я никак не определяю на какой странице нахожусь, это и есть часть моего вопроса

Comment: вы же знаете url запроса и разные страницы выводите как-то. Из этой информации можно понять какому пункту меню соответствует страница

Answer (score 1):

Если очень упрощённо, то можно так:

```
// Массив с названиями ваших модулей
$links = [
    '' => 'Главная',
    'map' => 'Карта',
    'faq' => 'FAQ',
    'auth' => 'Авторизация',
    'blog' => 'Блог'
];

$view = [];
$uri = explode('/', trim($_SERVER['PHP_SELF'], '/'))[0];

foreach ($links as $dir => $name) {
    if ($dir == $uri) {
        $view[] = "<span style='color:red;'>$name</span>";
    } else {
        $view[] = "<a href='http://sampwar.ru/$dir'>$name</a>";
    }
}

echo join(' | ', $view);
```

Результат:

```
Главная | Карта | FAQ | Авторизация | Блог
(текущая страница будет подсвечена)
```